# SVG - fluid layout - text scaling inside fluid container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg

i have a SVG doc embedded in a bootstrap span12 div.

```
<div class="box span12">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<text y="10" width="20">Hello World</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

I want my SVG to expand dynamically with the span12 container, which i accomplished with the viewBox attribute. I also want the text inside the SVG element to be "floated" on the left and have 20% width of the SVG document, so i can put other elements on the right. I have set the width to 20, but for some reason my text is not scaling inside the SVG to 20% and instead is scaling over the whole document.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks